# How to find one's illustrious ancestors

Tags: family-members, genealogy

If someone does not know his family tree — for example, he is the child of ba'alei teshuveh and his grandparents did not impart to his parents any important-to-Judaism information about his forebears — how can he find out whether he has any important-to-Judaism ancestors?

Comment: This question belongs here: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/.